# d3.js bar chart is not updating based on click event

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Here is my jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/dibyendu/3b0rjpe4/ . Basically based on `clicked donut text` I want to update my `bar chart` below. If `onclick` `text` turns `red` then `bar` should be hided and  if `onclick` `text` turns `black` then `bar` should be shown again.

I know the issue is with

```
selection.exit().remove();
```

which I am not sure where I am missing here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: To do this I wouldn't even use `selection.exit().remove();` I would give each selection a class, then on click show that specific class and hide all the others. I will put together an example now if that helps

Comment: But will it help my bar chart to reorder , If I hide and show based on class then the order will be not changed right. The bars will be at same place. Thoughts ?

Comment: reorder ? What do you mean ?

Comment: Yes means if I click `M1` in my example then `M2` should be the first bar in my bar graph since `M1` is hide now and same if I click again `M1` back then it should again appear first and `M2` second

Comment: Ah ok I didn't realise that, ill have a look

Comment: @thatOneGuy I believe my code is reordering or rearranging the bars but they are overlapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I am able to fix it here https://jsfiddle.net/dibyendu/czfg562r/ .

Once clicked deleted all the childs under that `svg` by

```
svg.selectAll("*").remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing something like this `d3.select('#'+ids).remove();` where `ids` is the `id d.id` which you use to bind the chart. So that whenever you click your pie chart your old DOM gets replaced with the new DOM elements. More over place class to the particular element which you are replacing or else just put a class to `svg` and replace with the new `svg` something like this `d3.select("svg").remove();`.

Comment: If i do this `d3.select("svg").remove();` it will remove the `svg` . But actually I want to replace it.